# How to highlight multiple keywords in a mouthful in PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

Suppose there are 3 keywords,

I don't want to do this kind of replace 3 times:

```
a => <b>a</b>

str_replace ( 'a', '<b>a</b>', $str)
```

Is it possible to do it by one run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strtr (or mb_strtr) function in PHP

```
$trans = array("hello" => "hi", "said" => "screamed");
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello", $trans);  // prints out "hi all, I screamed hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a backreference:

```
$text = "foo bar baz";
echo preg_replace('/(a)/', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(a|e|i|o|u)/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```

have you considered looking into `<b>` vs `<strong>` ?